# When executing CGI, give me only plain text

Tags: cgi

When I tried to execute CGI, it gives me only plain text.

I installed PHP5.3.11 with apache2
All of them were installed manually from source code, not from apt-get

```
## Apache2
./configure --prefix/=usr/loca/apache2
make
make install

## php5
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php5 --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs
make
make test
make install
```

The above are commands that I used to install apache2 and php5.
I guess my installation for apache2 and php5 is correct, since I can run php code on my server. So I tried to execute CGI script after properly, I guess, setting a configuration.
However it shows only plain text of CGI script.

```
###Start###

#!/usr/bin/perl -w
print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
print "Hello there!<br />\nJust testing .<br />\n";

for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    print $i."<br />";
}

###End###
```

perl is properly installed at /usr/bin/perl.

I set my httpd.conf like below.

```
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I think cgi-php5 is installed correctly as well, since when I execute "php-cgi -h", it gives me a result.
And when I open phpinfo() through browser,
GATEWAY_INTERFACE is set to CGI/1.1

Any thing I am missing? I appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
my mistake was on httpd.conf and it was really stupid mistake. :-(

I had to uncomment the following line.

LoadModule cgi-script blahblah

No one knows how many hour I spend for this stupid mistake :-(